# How to upload only the file(mp4/mp3/pdf) given the path to the file to a cloud storage like s3 or spaces(Digital-Oceans)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fs

Trying to read a video file using a relative path using fs.readfilesync(path) to upload to S3 bucket but the whole folder tree is being uploaded to S3.(in my case Spaces(digital ocean))

```
const file = fs.readFileSync('./downloads/this.movie_details.title/Understanding Network Hacks Attack And Defense With Python/Understanding Network Hacks Attack And Defense With Python.pdf');
const filename = video_path;
        
var params = {
               Body: file,
               Bucket: 'ocean-bucket21',
               Key: filename,
              };
                 
s3.putObject(params, function (err, data) { });
```

The result of the above code in the cloud is the whole file structure  is uploaded instead of only one file i.e. pdf

[image: the image shows the file that is uploaded to bucket]

Comment: Where is the value of `filename` being set?

Comment: yeah man, I set the key to   key: video_path  , my bad.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are saying that you'd like to upload the file to the top-level (root) of the bucket, rather than putting it inside the folders.

If so, then you should modify the `Key` value in the `params` dictionary. The `Key` includes the **full path** of the object. If the `Key` contains slashes, they will be interpreted as directory names.

If you want it at the top-level, edit the value of `Key` so it just contains your desired filename.